# Set html relative root links in site to specific folder in root in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, hyperlink

I have one master hosting account in which I host multiple websites. Each folder directly under the root is a website. In the websites, I'm wanting to start using relative root links on my assets, but when I do, the sites try to look in the master root, for which they are not there. Is there any way to add a snippet to the .htaccess file located in each site's "root" so when a specific website page tries looking up assets, it knows to go to said website's root folder and not the master?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteBase /master/subsite_x/
```